# Windows Runtime activatable class in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm getting an error when I try to register an activatable class for WinRT. This is in a C# universal app (UAP) in Visual Studio 2015, on Windows 10.

Previously, you could register activatable classes in your Package.appxmanifest file like this:

```
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
        <Path>myCode.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="myNS.MyNativeClass" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

But Visual Studio doesn't like this. It's violating the schema for a UAP project's appxmanifest file:

```
Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 42, Column 20, Reason: 'windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer' violates enumeration constraint of 'windows.backgroundTasks windows.preInstalledConfigTask windows.updateTask windows.restrictedLaunch'. The attribute 'Category' with value 'windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer' failed to parse.  TextSecure  C:\Users\123\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\MyProj\MyProj\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

So how do you use Windows Runtime components from a UAP project? Without registering it, you get a TypeLoadException.

Comment: So why did you tag the question C++ if it is C#?

Comment: Works fine when I try this.  Are you typing this in by hand instead of letting MSBuild auto-generate it?  Then you need to show the full manifest.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Bo. The app itself is C#. The Windows Runtime component is C++. Hans, if I reference the project it works for me too. My NuGet package is missing a step. Me experimenting by manually putting this in the appxmanifest is part of figuring that out. I put the full file here https://gist.github.com/langboost/2f32eff6b042e172804d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you put the Extensions element, in the Application element or Package Element?
If you put it in Application element, this error is expected. You should put in in the Package element.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>yourdll.dll</Path>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```

Comment: My extension was in the application section. That was what caused the error. I was not aware there are two places for extension elements in the file, and placed it there by mistake. Thanks!